# How to use a plist as a kind of storage in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, plist

I wrote an app with a MapKit View and I have multiple annotations shown on the map. I used arrays for the longitudes, the latitudes and names of the places, and it works perfectly fine. But as more and more places are added, it gets very hard to find the data for a specific place. I would like to use a plist to store the data of each place in an own array, but I could not find out how to access the plist and the specific data needed.

I only tried to create a plist and inside the Root Dictionary I created array, with each array containing Item 0 as String "Name of the Place", Item 1 as Number (LatitudeNumber) and Item 2 as Number (LongitudeNumber).

```
@IBOutlet var Map: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let laditudeArray = [47.828640, 47.737929, 48.065218, 48.140537]
    let longitudeArray = [16.609410, 16.511681, 16.924627, 16.824681]
    let nameArray = ["Place A", "Place B", "Place C", "Place D"]

    var index = 0

    while index < nameArray.count {

    let places = MKPointAnnotation()
        places.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: laditudeArray[index], longitude: longitudeArray[index])
    places.subtitle = nameArray[index]

    Map.addAnnotation(places)

    index = index + 1

    }

}
```

I would like to get the value from Item 0 of the array in the plist (which is the name of the place) into places.subtitle.

Comment: First of all you should structure your data, make it conform to Codable, encode it and save it as a json text file

Comment: @LeoDabus - I agree re `Codable`, but why insist that he `JSONEncoder` and not `PropertyListEncoder`, or example, especially when he asked about property lists?

Comment: @Rob I prefer using json instead of plist that's all. The main point is to get rid of the multiple arrays

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`PropertyListEncoder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/propertylistencoder) and [`PropertyListDecoder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/propertylistdecoder).

To do this, you can make a custom type that conforms to `Codable`:

```
struct Place: Codable {
    let name: String
    let latitude: CLLocationDegrees
    let longitude: CLLocationDegrees
}
```

Then you can create your array like so:

```
let places = [
    Place(name: "Place A", latitude: 47.828640, longitude: 16.609410),
    Place(name: "Place B", latitude: 47.737929, longitude: 16.511681),
    Place(name: "Place C", latitude: 48.065218, longitude: 16.924627),
    Place(name: "Place D", latitude: 48.140537, longitude: 16.824681)
]
```

To save it to a plist:

```
do {
    let fileURL = try FileManager.default
        .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        .appendingPathComponent("places.plist")

    let data = try PropertyListEncoder().encode(places)
    try data.write(to: fileURL)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

To read from plist:

```
do {
    let fileURL = ...
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
    let places = try PropertyListDecoder().decode([Place].self, from: data)
    print(places)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

By the way, if you need your array of annotations to add to your map from this array of `places`, you can:

```
let annotations = places.map { place -> MKPointAnnotation in
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.title = place.name
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: place.latitude, longitude: place.longitude)
    return annotation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider something a little more flexible, in the form of a struct conforming to Codable:

```
struct Place: Codable {
    let latitiude: Double
    let longitude: Double
    let name: String
}

var myPlaces = [
    Place(latitiude: 47.828640, longitude: 16.609410, name: "Place A"),
    Place(latitiude: 47.737929, longitude: 16.511681, name: "Place B"),
    Place(latitiude: 48.065218, longitude: 16.924627, name: "Place C"),
    Place(latitiude: 48.140537, longitude: 16.824681, name: "Place D")
]

// Saving places:
func save(places: [Place]) throws {
    do {
        let encoded = try PropertyListEncoder().encode(places)
        let url = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("places.json")
        try encoded.write(to: url)
    }
}

// Loading places:
func loadPlaces() -> [Place]? {
    let url = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("places.json")
    guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else { return nil }
    return try? PropertyListDecoder().decode([Place].self, from: data)
}

// Helper from https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-find-the-users-documents-directory
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}
```

Usage is then:

```
// To save:
do {
    try save(places: myPlaces)
} catch {
    // Couldn't save for some reason - look into the thrown exception
}

// To load, allowing for the initial condition that there are
// not yet any saved places to be loaded
myPlaces = loadPlaces() ?? []
```

Populating your map then becomes something like:

```
// Turn every `Place` into an MKPointAnnotation
myPlaces.map { place -> MKPointAnnotation in
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: place.latitiude,
                                                   longitude: place.longitude)
    annotation.subtitle = place.name
    return annotation
}
// ... and add them to our map
.forEach(map.addAnnotation)
```

**Hint:** Don't use variable names with initial capitals. It makes them look like type names and will cause confusion in the future (e.g. `@IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!` would be preferred).

**Hint:** If you ever find yourself manually keeping track of an array index, that's a good sign you should probably be considering [`forEach` or `for x in y`](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/76/how-to-loop-over-arrays) or [`map`](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-use-map-to-transform-an-array), especially if the value is *only* used as an index. If the value itself matters (e.g. `title = "This is section \(idx)"`) then `.enumerated` is your friend.

**Hint:** If you want your saved data to be more human readable/editable, or perhaps to be delivered by a web service, consider JSONEncoder/JSONDecoder instead.

Comment: True, but JSON has the advantage of being more readily human readable/editable.